How to make properties of OWNED class required conditionally
How to make properties of a class required only sometimes. Using an ADDRESS class, my model will require properties for a corporate office. For the Offsite facility (which may not exist), I need to make the properties optional.
I would like to make the CorpOffice Street, City, State, and Zip required. I am trying to get the Validation Results collection to have the missing properties when the entire application is validated using Validator.TryValidateObject(...).
[Owned]
public class Address : BaseModel
{
    public string? Street { get => _Street; set { _Street = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Street)); } }

    private string? _Street;
    

    public string? Mailing { get => _Mailing; set { _Mailing = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Mailing)); } }

    private string? _Mailing;


    public string? City { get => _City; set { _City = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(City)); } }

    private string? _City;


    public virtual State? State { get => _State; set { _State = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(State)); } }

    private State? _State;


    public int? Zip { get => _Zip; set { _Zip = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Zip)); } }

    private int? _Zip;


    public int? Zip4 { get => _Zip4; set { _Zip4 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Zip4)); } }

    private int? _Zip4;
}


public class Application
{
    [Required]
    public Address CorpOffice { get; set; }

    public Address Offsite_Facility { get; set; }
}


Avoid mixing domain and UI concerns. Entities should reflect data state while validation/notification are a front-end concern and belong in a ViewModel.

If your class implements IValidatableObject you can add a Validate method implementing those requirements.

So based on pjs comment on my question, this is what I have come up with.
public class Application : IValidatableObject
{

    // Other properties that require validation decorated with the [Required] attribute 

    public Address CorpOffice { get; set; }

    public Address Offsite_Facility { get; set; }



    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CorpOffice.Street))
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("Street address is required", ["CorpOffice.Street"]));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CorpOffice.City))
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("City is required", ["CorpOffice.City"]));

        if (CorpOffice.State == null || CorpOffice.State.StateId == 0)
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("State is required", ["CorpOffice.State"]));

        if (CorpOffice.Zip == null || CorpOffice.Zip == 0)
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("Zip Code is required", ["CorpOffice.Zip"]));

        if (CorpOffice.Zip > 99999)
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("Zip Code cannot be more than 5 numbers", ["CorpOffice.Zip"]));

        if(CorpOffice.Zip4 > 9999)
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("Zip + 4 cannot be more than 4 numbers", ["CorpOffice.Zip4"]));


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Offsite_Facility.Street))
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("Street address is required", ["Offsite_Facility.Street"]));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Offsite_Facility.City))
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("City is required", ["Offsite_Facility.City"]));

        if (Offsite_Facility.State == null || Offsite_Facility.State.StateId == 0)
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("State is required", ["Offsite_Facility.State"]));

        if (Offsite_Facility.Zip == null || Offsite_Facility.Zip == 0)
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("Zip Code is required", ["Offsite_Facility.Zip"]));

        if (Offsite_Facility.Zip > 99999)
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("Zip Code cannot be more than 5 numbers", ["Offsite_Facility.Zip"]));

        if (Offsite_Facility.Zip4 > 9999)
    results.Add(new ValidationResult("Zip + 4 cannot be more than 4 numbers", ["Offsite_Facility.Zip4"]));

        return results;
    }
}

And then I run my checks in my logic
...
ValidationResults = [];

// If there are validation errors, fill the results collection
Validator.TryValidateObject(NewApplication, new ValidationContext(NewApplication), ValidationResults, validateAllProperties: true);

 // Run the custom validation
 foreach(var val in NewApplication.Validate(new ValidationContext(NewApplication)))
     ValidationResults.Add(val);
...

